# Allow VBA code inside protected worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I recorded the below VBA code that hide/unhide rows then sort on worksheet_Activate event, in no time :). Just one thing, the worksheet is required to be protected and this code refuse to be executed in a protected sheet and got this error message :

> "run-time error 1004 "You cannot use this commend on a protected
>   sheet..."

Could you please advise how we can protect the sheet and allow this code at the same time?

```
Sub HIDESORT()
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$10:$K$500").AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:=">0", _
        Operator:=xlAnd
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Control Implementation Plan").AutoFilter.Sort. _
        SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Control Implementation Plan").AutoFilter.Sort. _
        SortFields.Add Key:=Range("G10:G500"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:= _
        xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Control Implementation Plan").AutoFilter.Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: when you protect the worksheet you've to allow users the possibility to hide/unhide cells by selecting the checkbox allow `format columns`. Try adding this segment to your code
`ActiveSheet.Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True, AllowFormattingColumns:=True `

Comment: Worked perfectly ;) thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
ActiveSheet.Protect UserInterfaceOnly:=True
```

Comment: @AhmedElAmrani Note that if you want to prevent other sections of code from updating the sheet (perhaps as a failsafe that would prevent code from erroneously doing what you don't want), you could instead turn protection off at the beginning of the sub, and then turn it back on at the end of the sub. Otherwise, this method is likely best for your purposes.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon yes, this sounds good for me, could please suggest a simple code to do this ?

Comment: At the start: ActiveSheet.Protect    -    At the End: ActiveSheet.Unprotect

Comment: I think you meant the other way around :)

Comment: Yah, to have the worksheet protected all time for normal users, and allow the code to be executed. Only the vba code can change the worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

when you protect the worksheet you've to allow users the possibility to hide/unhide cells by selecting the checkbox allow `format columns`. Try adding this segment to your code

```
ActiveSheet.Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True, AllowFormattingColumns:=True
```